# Why recyclerview showing only Zero position value?

Tags: android

I am facing a strange error where recyclerview is showing only a single item.
I am using databinding with recylerview..... Below is code for my recyclerview adapter

```
public class ImageSetAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageSetAdapter.PictureItemHolder> {

    List<HouseModelSet> data;

    public ImageSetAdapter( List<HouseModelSet> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public PictureItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_home_picture,parent,false);
        /*ItemHomePictureBinding itemHomePictureBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.item_home_picture, parent, false);*/

        ItemHomePictureBinding binding = ItemHomePictureBinding.inflate(inflater,parent,false);

        return new PictureItemHolder(binding.getRoot());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PictureItemHolder holder, int position) {
        HouseModel hm1 = data.get(position).getHouseModels().get(0);
        HouseModel hm2 = data.get(position).getHouseModels().get(1);
        HouseModel hm3 = data.get(position).getHouseModels().get(2);
        HouseModel hm4 = data.get(position).getHouseModels().get(3);
        HouseModel hm5 = data.get(position).getHouseModels().get(4);
        holder.binding.house1.setHouse(hm1);
        holder.binding.house2.setHouse(hm2);
        holder.binding.house3.setHouse(hm3);
        holder.binding.house4.setHouse(hm4);
        holder.binding.house5.setHouse(hm5);
    }

    @BindingAdapter("android:src")
    public static void loadImage(ImageView imageView, int v){
        Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load(v).into(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class PictureItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ItemHomePictureBinding binding;

        public PictureItemHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is code for MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    ImageSetAdapter mImageSetAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);

        //--------Set and Get Tool Bar-------//
        setSupportActionBar(binding.appbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

        mImageSetAdapter = new ImageSetAdapter(getHousesSet());

        binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(mImageSetAdapter);
    }

    private List<HouseModelSet> getHousesSet() {
        List<HouseModelSet> list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<HouseModel> houses = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            HouseModel houseModel1 = new HouseModel("City "    + i, 1.34f + i , R.drawable.home8);
            HouseModel houseModel2 = new HouseModel("Sialkot " + i, 2.43f + i,R.drawable.home8);
            HouseModel houseModel3 = new HouseModel("Sialkot " + i, 3.43f + i,R.drawable.home8);
            HouseModel houseModel4 = new HouseModel("Sialkot " + i, 4.43f + i,R.drawable.home8);
            HouseModel houseModel5 = new HouseModel("Sialkot " + i, 5.43f + i,R.drawable.home8);

            houses.add(houseModel1);
            houses.add(houseModel2);
            houses.add(houseModel3);
            houses.add(houseModel4);
            houses.add(houseModel5);
        }
        list.add(new HouseModelSet(houses));
        return list;
    }
```

android Here is my xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@drawable/home8"
    tools:showIn="@layout/item_home_picture">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@{house.image}" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        style="@style/item_image_text_price"
        android:layout_above="@+id/city"
        android:text="@{String.valueOf(house.price)}"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/city"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        style="@style/item_image_text_city"
        android:text="@{house.city}"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my container layout

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cataorytxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="New Apartments"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_city"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Sialkot"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp">

                    <include android:id="@+id/house1"
                        layout="@layout/house_container_item" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">

                    <include android:id="@+id/house2"
                        layout="@layout/house_container_item" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:weightSum="4">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp">

                    <include android:id="@+id/house3"
                        layout="@layout/house_container_item" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">

                    <include android:id="@+id/house4"
                        layout="@layout/house_container_item" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <include android:id="@+id/house5"
                layout="@layout/house_container_item" />

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: getHousesSet returns with the size of 1 item

Comment: Thanks Ramesh you just Solve my problem......

Comment: One more Question Ramesh....I just put    list.add(new HouseModelSet(houses)); In side  FOR Loop ....It give my Four Times but each time IT show value of i=0..........?If you don't understand my words than pls tell me

Answer (score 1):

Your list only call once.

```
list.add(new HouseModelSet(houses));
```

Change your function like that

```
private List<HouseModelSet> getHousesSet() {
    List<HouseModelSet> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        List<HouseModel> houses = new ArrayList<>();
        HouseModel houseModel1 = new HouseModel("City "    + i, 1.34f + i , R.drawable.home8);
        HouseModel houseModel2 = new HouseModel("Sialkot " + i, 2.43f + i,R.drawable.home8);
        HouseModel houseModel3 = new HouseModel("Sialkot " + i, 3.43f + i,R.drawable.home8);
        HouseModel houseModel4 = new HouseModel("Sialkot " + i, 4.43f + i,R.drawable.home8);
        HouseModel houseModel5 = new HouseModel("Sialkot " + i, 5.43f + i,R.drawable.home8);

        houses.add(houseModel1);
        houses.add(houseModel2);
        houses.add(houseModel3);
        houses.add(houseModel4);
        houses.add(houseModel5);
        list.add(new HouseModelSet(houses));
    }

    return list;
}
```

Your RecyclerView is fine but it only get the first 5 item in the list.

Since you have put **25 items into the first position of the list** and your recyclerview only **have 1 size of the list**  and then the **first 5 items of the list** . That's why you can only view the single item in your view.

Comment: creating of houses list should also go inside for loop

Comment: @V-master , Thanks I missed that statement too.

Comment: Thanks buddy It's work....but when I just put list.add(new HouseModelSet(houses)); In side FOR Loop ....It give my Four Times but each time IT show value of i=0..........?If you don't understand my words than pls tell me

Comment: What do you mean i=0? Do you mean every houseModel shown "City 0" ? but not "City 1","City 2","City 3"...?.

Comment: OK, first problem is about the looping problem. Now the next one should be data binding problem, would u like to post your xml with "layout" tag and the corresponding variable ( which is used in android-databinding) ?